# .NET http network requests with Windows service

Tags: c#, http, windows-services, request

today i wrote a windows service which needs to send regular http requests to a server.
the problem is that the service runs under the "SYSTEM" account as local service and as such a type of service it isn't allowed to access the network.. for installing the service i use this class:

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/152585/ServiceInstaller.cs
```

is there a way to send http requests in a .net c# windows service and get the http response?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not run the service under a specific identity? Or the Network Service identity?

Take a look at this: it should help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676916(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: i don't know how to do this.. any example source code would be very nice :) do i have to install the service as for example a network service? then how to do that with my serviceinstaller class?

Comment: In the services control manager. (start> run, type "services.msc") you can choose the service and change the account it runs on in the Logon tab.

Comment: You can't. You cant't write your service to install on a specific account...that would be a security concern. You'll have to set the account on install. You could also possibly use WMI to change the account that the service runs on.

Comment: hmm.. setting it on install would be okay.. but the class for installing i found an mentioned above doesn't seem to support this.. so how to change the account on install?

Comment: when you install it, windows should prompt you for the account to use. Are you using InstallUtil?

Comment: no i'm not. i'm using this class i mentioned above because the service should install itself. at first launch the service installs itself and starts itself. after the next reboot its started automatically. so there is no gui i can use for changing something..

Answer (score 0):

I run networked services I've built as LocalSystem and have not had this problem.  Perhaps it is because the domain is granting network access to computer accounts.

Comment: do you see them running as user SYSTEM in task manager? or as network services?